# String insert no Ruby para JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

como posso fazer o código abaixo em Ruby para JS.

```
(3...value_size).step(3) { |num|
   value.insert(value_size - num, separator)
}
```

Para `step` Eu penso nesse loop `for (var i = 3; i < value_size; i += 3)`, mas para o método `.insert`? Qual suas ideias?

Comment: Por favor, traduza sua pergunta para o português.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's not written in Portuguese. It may be reopened if translated.

Comment: Desculpa, atualizado!